# Is there a mathematical theory of physical (or other) quantities?

Tags: abstract-algebra, physics

*Please try to be lenient with me since I have a hard time formalizing this question. I'm not even a physicist.*

Many people are probably familiar with Newton's second law:

$F = ma$

Like other physical laws it expresses a relationship between physical quantities. To make this mathematically precise, I suppose one could say, that we have functions $F,m,a : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ (that are "mapping time" to force, mass and acceleration), s.t. $F = m\cdot a$ in the obvious ring of functions $\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$. On the other hand this seems fairly arbitrary. One could argue that these quantities have nothing to do with time at all, maybe they have to with something else entirely.

Let's say we work in one-dimension and somebody tells us at some point, that $a$ actually depends entirely on how far our object has travelled, so $a$ "depends" on the "distance" $s$ from the origin. While we could express $s$ in terms of time, I'm not necessarily sure that we should. What makes the choice of time as our "independent variable" more canonical then choosing our "distance" $s$ for example?

This brings me to my question:

> Is there a mathematical theory of physical (or other) quantities, that
>   reflects how physicists (in my experience) seem to use them and where
>   we need not choose specific "independent variables"?

Here are some more vague thoughts:

The general idea I have is that it could be like this: We have a field $\mathbb{K}$ (or something like that) and a set of "quantities" $Q$. Then there is another field $\mathbb{K}_Q$ with an injection $\eta_{1,Q} : Q\to \mathbb{K}$ and a field morphism $\eta_{2,\mathbb{K}} : \mathbb{K} \to \mathbb{K}_Q$ (necessarily injective too), s.t. for all other fields $K$ with same set-up there is a unique field morphism $\mathbb{K}_Q \to K$ making "everything" commute, or something like that.

Comment: The entirety of theoretical physics is a bunch of mathematical theories of physical quantities. Can you be more specific as to what interests you? Classical mechanics or something?

Comment: @krvolok No theory in particular, rather a theory for theories.

Comment: Well, you might want to check out http://ncatlab.org/, where category theory is used to talk about physics and classify it. Category theory is broad enough to be able to do that, I don't think anything else could do it. Again, I'm just speculating on what might interest you!

Comment: Independence is relative. In physics (and I'm no physicist either) it seems most things boil down to time, at least when attempting a practical application. For example, if considering force as $F:\mathbb{R\times R}\to \mathbb R$, $F(m,a)=ma$, in experiment mass and acceleration might be functions of time: $m(t)$ and/or $a(t)$, so that $F:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$, $F(t)=m(t)a(t)$. Or, $a$ may be dependent on distance, and distance on time. It's useful to consider $m,a$ as independent to gain knowledge of the behavior of $F$ at specific values of $m$ and $a$.

Comment: @krvolok I would, but my knowledge of category theory is not nearly as advanced I'm afraid ;).

Comment: $F=ma$ is *never used*, though, and dynamics are obtained from making the appropriate action functional stationary, or by considering $(T^* M,\omega)$, a cotangent space on a manifold (determined by constraints, or geometry of a problem) and a nondegenerate 2-form $\omega$: this induces dynamics naturally as integral curves of a vector field $X_H$ where (modulo minus signs!) $\omega(X_H,\cdot)=\mathrm d H$, where $H$ is called a Hamiltonian, which specifies dynamics completely (it is also identified with energy). All this for just classical mechanics! Also the $m$ has a big story of its own...

Comment: Perhaps [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert%27s_sixth_problem) is slightly related to the question?

Comment: @krvolok Maybe the only reason I'm asking this question is because I know nothing about differential geometry or any actual mathematical models of physics...

Comment: It's ok! :) You have a problem, because most 'introduction to physics' texts are very elementary, but advanced treatments take most things you'd be interested about (sort of 'foundational' things, like what's the m in F=ma) for granted and are very specialized. You should try reading Spivak's Physics for mathematicians (is it called like that? I haven't read it but from what I've heard it might be what you want).

Comment: You may take a look at the article A Mathematical Theory of Dimensions and Units of  Physical Quantities by Mario Bunge appearing in _Problems in the Foundations of Physics_. It could be helpful, I guess.